# Phonegap sqlite update query not working

Tags: sqlite, cordova

I have an update query, where in I am updating a Boolean column to true, it goes in the success callback but when I fetch same value it is false.
Below is my code snippet:

```
    db.transaction(function(tx){
        tx.executeSql("update `"+UsersT+"` set "+LoggedInC+" = 'true' where "+UserIdC+" = '18' ", [], function(tx,res){
            alert("it goes here");
            getUser();
        }, function(err){
            alert("Error code: "+err.code);
        });
    }, function(err){});


function getUser(){
    db.transaction(function(tx){
        tx.executeSql("select * from `"+UsersT+"` where "+UserIdC+" = 18 ", [],function(tx, res){
            alert(res.rows.length+" | "+res.rows.item(0).logged_in+" | "+res.rows.item(0).uid);
        }, function(err){alert("Error: "+err.code);});
    }, function(err){});
}
```

Thanks

Any help ?